# CSS - expand div

Tags: css

http://t-webdesign.co.uk/new/

How would i go about getting the grey div (#content_right) to expand to the same size as the left hand side div without using a fixed height attribute?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to check [the equal height columns technique out](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks):